# Why is Arivanya dead inside New Gnisis Cornerclub?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

[image: Arivanya lying dead on the floor]
[image: Arivanya lying dead on the floor]

Arivanya, who was killed by butcher during "Blood On the Ice" quest, has somehow ended up inside New Gnisis Cornerclub, along with scattered pieces of wood just like the inside of Hjerim. what makes it bizzare is that the people inside will act like there's nothing wrong at all, only leaving comments like "What a waste" and then just going back to minding their own business :/.

I've already completed Blood on the Ice (part 1 and 2) so why is Arivanya here and how can I get rid of her body?

Comment: Well, whatever the reason is, it's probably a random one time glitch with your playthrough.  Nobody else has reported this problem, and Skyrim is an old game...

Comment: It might be 6 years old (does that make it 'an old game' now?) but it's still being actively sold and updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't really know what the cause was. Probably a bug. **But after ignoring it for a while the body finally disappeared**. Probably it is because the interior will eventually reset and thus fixed the problem.